# Accessing mysql database in docker container from flask container using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, docker, pymysql

Hi guys I understand there are a lot of threads on this topic, however I have been unable to find anything that works and am I completely stuck.

my Docker-Compose file looks like :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 9090:5000
    links:
      - db:database

  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image:  mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
```

and I am trying to connect using

```
def database_controller(cmd):
    connection=db.connect(host="database", port=3306, user="root", password="pass", database="main")
    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
            cursor.execute(cmd)
            result = cursor.fetchall()

            connection.commit()
            connection.close()
            return result
```

This results in an error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a database called "main"?

Comment: @user7065687 You know what I don't think I do, I thought that the line MYSQL_DATABASE: main automatically creates a database called main

Comment: No it doesn't. You need to create it by yourself first.

Comment: `MYSQL_DATABASE` should create a database with that name, _if_ this is the first time the database container was started (see "Environment Variables" in the [`mysql` Docker Hub image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).  You shouldn't need the obsolete `links:` option at this point though, and the error message would be much more readable if it was in text rather than image form.